# Ruby Fibonacci doesn't work?

Tags: ruby

I was trying to generate the nth Fibonacci number in Ruby, here's my code:

```
def fib(n)
  x=1
  y=1
  z=0
  res=0
  while z < n
    z=x+y
    if z%2==0 
      res+=z
      x=y
      y=z
    end
  end
  return res
end
```

But it results in an infinite loop. What's the problem?

Comment: where is *base* condition...???

Comment: @ArupRakshit Shouldn't it terminate when `z >=n`?

Comment: @user3565419 that is the idea, yes, but Z stops changing as soon as it becomes an odd number due to `if z%2==0`

Comment: @JanDvorak yup, I put my `end` for the first `if` in the wrong place. My bad, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`z` appears to only advance for odd sums of `x+y`.  Since `x+y` is initialized 2, `z` remains unchanged throughout the loop.  This is an infinite loop for any n greater than 2.

Comment: @user3565419 I don't consider this question worth keeping. That's why I didn't post an answer.

Comment: @JanDvorak Okay, do you think I should remove it? it was a stupid mistake.

Comment: @user3565419 that's what I'm suggesting.

Comment: @JanDvorak I can't delete it. It says I need to flag for moderator attention. Can you do that?

Answer (score 1):

It is because the value of `z` stops changing after the second step.

After the first step, `z=2`, `x=1` and `y=2`. Then, you do `z=x+y` again and now `z=3`, but since `z%2==1`, you don't change the values of `x` and `y`, and you do `z=2+1` again and get `z=3`.